# bash output inside the terminal : command not found

Tags: bash

**Hi everyone,**

I wanted to ask a question about the bash output inside the terminal

**The following procedure generates a command not found :**

```
TEST:~ SniperDMC$
TEST:~ SniperDMC$ $HOSTNAME
-bash: TEST.local: command not found
```

**How to avoid this and beautify the output ?**

Best regards

SniperDMC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `$HOSTNAME` is a variable, and if you just write it on a single line and press enter, bash will simply replace it with the respective value, i.e. "TEST.local". Since "TEST.local" is not a valid command, bash will complain.

If you want to print the value of any bash variable, you should use `echo`, i.e. `echo $HOSTNAME`.

For a quick bash scripting tutorial regarding variables, [see here for example](https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-variables.php).

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. Is it possible that the bash recognizes the variable statement and do the "echo" via .bashrc ?

Comment: If you mean whether it's possible to have bash automatically `echo` every variable instead of "just" replacing it, then no, this is not a good idea (and probably impossible). If you're only looking for a solution regarding your host name, I'd recommend using `hostname` instead (note the small letters) which is the common utility for printing the hostname.